# WebGL: can't apply texture to object

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm attempting to apply a texture to an object in webGL, but I get the following error:

> WebGL warning: drawElements: Vertex attrib array 0 is enabled but has no buffer bound.

which I am unable to find any information on online. Otherwise the scene shows, but the object that needs the texture is appearing as a flat square.

The error points to my drawElements

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeNormalBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, cubeNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
  setMatrixUniforms();
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

and my buffer for the texture

```
  cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
  const textureCoords = [
      // Front
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      // Back
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      // Top
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      // Bottom
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      // Right
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      // Left
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
  cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = 24;
```

and the texture code

```
let texture;
function initTexture(){
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0,0,255,255]));
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        if(isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)){
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        else{
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        }
        drawScene();
    };
    // image.src = "crate.gif";
    image.src = "WoodFine23_COL_3K.jpg";
}
function isPowerOf2(value) {
    return(value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Otherwise my entire code can be found here https://pastebin.com/HaQBFEuL

Also, I have followed the following tutorials
http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1359,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL, 
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Lighting_in_WebGL

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `initShaders` the generic vertex attribute arrays for the indices `shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribut`, `shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute`, `shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute`,
`shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute` are enabled and they are never disabled in your code.

But in the function `drawScene` there are only defined the arrays of generic vertex attribute data for the indices `shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribut`, `shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute` and `shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute`.
`shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute` is missing because it is under comment.

The error messag

> WebGL warning: drawElements: Vertex attrib array 0 is enabled but has no buffer bound.

means, that there is a vertex attribute index, which is "enabled", but where are no data defined for.

In your case this is `shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute`, which is defined but not enabled.

Skip enabling the vertex attribute with index `shaderProgram.vertexColoAttribute` and your code should proper run. 
Of course the vertex attributes can be enable in the function `initShaders` and defined in the function `drawScene`. But the vertex attrbute `shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute` is enabled in the function `drawScene` too. You should not call `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` twice for the same attribute index, without of any need.